# Regarding Autolyout issue of dynamic tableView in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have three views simultaneously in mid of views i have a table view which has dynamic content as row increases table view height will also increase.Then my question is how to create origin of second view according to table view height?.

Comment: set in viewdidapppear method and just put NSlayoutconstrain of your first table hight and then set according to your requirement

Comment: @neha All three views are connected through `@IBOutlet` or you are creating it programmatically ?